# Universal sprite size

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

### Explanation

I'm trying to make my game work on iPhone and iPad. I created this testing project, but the sprites sizes only work with iPhone 6s Plus; in all other devices, the sprites are bad positioned (as you can see in the screenshots below). 

Is there any thing I can do, besides using `setScale` to downsize the sprites according to the device size (which I think, isn't the right way), to make it universal?

[image]

---

### Code

You can download the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gscrb9fetu0j3hv/AADOv8obPf-MIXcDW7iJDxA4a?dl=0).

**GameViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set view size.
        let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

**GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var bg = SKSpriteNode()
    var square = SKSpriteNode()
    var xIcon = SKSpriteNode()

    func addBG(){

        bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg")
        bg.size = (self.view?.bounds.size)!
        bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        bg.position = CGPointZero
        bg.zPosition = 0
        addChild(bg)
    }
    func addSquare(){

        square = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "square")
        square.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        square.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 - square.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 - square.frame.height / 2)
        square.zPosition = 1
        addChild(square)
    }
    func addxIcon(){

        xIcon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "xIcon")
        xIcon.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        xIcon.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / (4/3) - xIcon.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / (16/13) - xIcon.frame.height / 2)
        xIcon.zPosition = 2
        addChild(xIcon)
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        addBG()
        addSquare()
        addxIcon()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, 
Luiz.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the width of the screen as follows:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
```

And then set the size of elements relative to `screenWidth`.

Just in case you haven't figured it out yet, the 1x, 2x and 3x don't have anything to do with the size of the graphics on the screen. They just relate to the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work that way,  the 1x 2x 3x is the pixel to point ratio (every 3 pixels = 1 point is @3x)  Then you need to worry  about ppi (pixels per  inch.)  iPhone 6 offers more ppi than iPhone 5  If you have an iPhone 6 specific size, you are no longer making a universal app,  time to change your model, and specify graphics for specific devices.  <s>Go into your image assets,  and you will be able to assign specific graphics to each device.  (Note you can leave your universal as a default asset, and only specify 6 to use bigger assets).</s> (edit:Requires editing of JSON, not practical) If you want to stick to universal,  then ditch the `view.frame.size` (which you should not be using anyway) and use a specific scene size with some kind of `scalingMode` other than `.ResizeFill`.

Comment: By following Chris's suggestion, I created this `lazy var universalSize : CGFloat = CGFloat(self.frame.width / 1366)`, in which 1366 would be iPad Pro's width points (largest). So I could `setScale(universalSize)` to work in every device. It works, but I think that all this workaround isn't the right way to do it.

Comment: How can I use a specific image for each device? I can't find it in image assets. All I found was iPhone and iPad 1x, 2x, 3x (1x and 2x for iPad).

Comment: setScale(universalSize) it a terrible way to go,  you are right on the part about image assets,  I think I went into the json to force it, but regardless, if you are using setScale,  them you are doing it wrong, Set your scene size to the iPad size,  and then use aspect fill

Comment: but why should I set the scene size to the iPad size? Shouldn't it be the used device size, this way: `scene.size = view.bounds.size`?

Comment: no  scene.size = view.bounds.size should never be used,  you want that, set scale mode to .ResizeFill

Comment: I really wish these sprite kit tutorials were decent,  too many people are doing things they wish they never did,  The tutorial tells you to calculate  position  and scale every single item,  or you can use the scale mode the right way, and not calculate any positions, and let the device scale for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118501/discussion-between-luiz-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: Hi! It wasn't me. I've never voted down. You can see that I don't even have it's bagde.

Comment: I didn't think it was you

Comment: Sorry! I answered because I was notified only